# How to format code right after `setValue()` is called in the Monaco Editor?

Tags: javascript, formatting, monaco-editor

If you copy/paste the `code` into a Monaco Editor it gets instantly formatted due to `'formatOnPaste'`. But if you use the method `setValue`, and call the `"editor.action.formatDocument"` right after, nothing happens. I need to wrap it in a `setTimeout` Which visibly makes your code jump in the editor...

Any suggestions? You can copy/paste + click run the code below in a [playround](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html)

```js
var value = "function hello() {\nalert('Hello world!');\n}";

var instance = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    language: "javascript",
    formatOnPaste: true,
});


// Setup the listner for the model change
instance.getModel().onDidChangeContent(() => {
    // !! Comment out the setTimeout, nothing wil happen..
    setTimeout(() => {
        instance.getAction("editor.action.formatDocument").run();
        // instance.trigger("", 'editor.action.formatDocument');
    }, 100);
});

// Change the value...
instance.setValue(value);
```

Comment: I am curious to know if you ever found a solution to this @Dalie as I posted practically the same question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939385/how-do-i-format-json-code-in-monaco-editor-with-api

Comment: @WarrenBuckley when it concerns `JSON` you can use `JSON.stringify(jsonCode, null, 4)` where the last param defines the 'space' or indentation if you like. Hope it helps.

Comment: could you pls publish an answer to this