# How do I format JSON code in Monaco Editor with API?

Tags: javascript, json, monaco-editor

I am working with **monaco editor** aka the **VS Code** engine in a web project.

I am using it to allow users to edit some JSON that has a JSON Schema set, to help give some auto-completion.

When they save their changes and wish to re-edit their work, the JSON that I load back into the editor is converted to a string but this renders the code out on a single line and I would much prefer the JSON to be prettier as if the user right clicks and uses the Format Document command from the context menu or keyboard shortcut etc..

So this

```json
{ "enable": true, "description": "Something" }
```

Would become this

```json
{
    "enable": true,
    "description:" "Something"
}
```

### Current attempt

I have tried the following but it feels very hacky to use a timeout to wait/guess when the content has loaded

```js
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {

  // JSON object we want to edit
  const jsonCode = [{
    "enabled": true,
    "description": "something"
  }];

  const modelUri = monaco.Uri.parse("json://grid/settings.json");
  const jsonModel = monaco.editor.createModel(JSON.stringify(jsonCode), "json", modelUri);

  const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    model: jsonModel
  });

  // TODO: YUK see if we can remove timeout, as waiting for the model/content to be set is weird
  // Must be some nice native event?!
  // ALSO ITS SUPER JARRING WITH FLASH OF CHANGE
  setTimeout(function() {
    editor.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument').run();
  }, 100);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.19.3/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  require.config({
    paths: {
      'vs': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.19.3/min/vs'
    }
  });
</script>

<div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>
```

Does anyone have a better idea or solution to this please?

Comment: Can you please show the jsonModel?

Comment: No problem will update the example now... and yes I am using vintage tech with AngularJS :-P

Comment: I'm using this in the Azure Portal and right click does not even work, if anyone knows why, please add a comment below.

Comment: Is this demo of [json formatter](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/formatter/json) what you want? Then just use `value={formattedJsonString}` via [@monaco-editor/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```js
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {

  // JSON object we want to edit
  const jsonCode = [{
    "enabled": true,
    "description": "something"
  }];

  const modelUri = monaco.Uri.parse("json://grid/settings.json");
  const jsonModel = monaco.editor.createModel(JSON.stringify(jsonCode, null, '\t'), "json", modelUri);

  const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    model: jsonModel
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.19.3/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  require.config({
    paths: {
      'vs': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.19.3/min/vs'
    }
  });
</script>

<div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1378051/dalie for reminding me about the extra arguments to JSON.stringify

### Answer

Use the tab character for the space argument
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

`const jsonModel = monaco.editor.createModel(JSON.stringify(jsonCode, null, '\t'), "json", modelUri);`

Answer (score 2):

I use this function to tidy my code:

```
tidy() {
  this.monacoEditor.trigger('anyString', 'editor.action.formatDocument')
}
```

where `monacoEditor` is result of  `this.monacoEditor = monaco.editor.create(this.$el, { ...this.editorOptions })`